# Select query in CQL issue

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I am trying to get the count of a table in cassandra DB, i am running the below query:

```
select count(*) 
from bssapi.call_detail_records 
WHERE 
year = 2020 
and month = 3
and event_at > '2020-03-01 07:45:51+0000' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

The error which i am getting is:

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Partitioning column "year" cannot be restricted because the preceding column ("ColumnDefinition{name=subscription_id, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=PARTITION_KEY, componentIndex=0, indexName=null, indexType=null}") is either not restricted or is restricted by a non-EQ relation"
```

When i filter the query by adding a subscription ID, the system return the count correctly, this issue appear only when i run the count for all the table.

Comment: Can you share your schema for this table?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this issue, i used the below query instead:

```
select COUNT(*) from bssapi.call_detail_records WHERE event_at > '2020-03-22 07:45:51+0000' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Comment: if you  use `ALLOW FILTERING` - it's a first sign that you're doing something wrong, and you need to change data model, or use other tools, such as, Spark. Otherwise you'll start to get problems as soon as size of your data grows...

Comment: The fact that @AlexOtt's comment has more upvotes than the answer it's on, should indicate that Alex is probably correct here.